# onClick crash Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, onclick

I'm creating a simple microwave power calculator app in Android Studio. I've only just downloaded this tonight and haven't written anything for Android before.

My code shows no errors yet when I run the app on my phone it force closes when I hit the calculate button, with the following error in the log.

```
01-09 02:33:43.885  12397-12397/com.microwave D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-09 02:33:48.319  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:48.319  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:48.870  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:48.870  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:50.591  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:50.591  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:51.862  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:51.862  12397-12397/com.microwave W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-09 02:33:53.404  12397-12397/com.microwave W/ResourceType﹕ No known package when getting value for resource number 0xffffff38
01-09 02:33:53.404  12397-12397/com.microwave D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-09 02:33:53.404  12397-12397/com.microwave W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ed6d40)
01-09 02:33:53.414  12397-12397/com.microwave E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.microwave, PID: 12397
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1270)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1086)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1270)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1086)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffff38
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
            at android.content.res.XResources.getText(XResources.java:696)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
            at com.microwave.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:62)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1270)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1086)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the rest of the code and the XML. I assume I have something very basic wrong as I'm just using prior basic Java knowledge and know nothing about android.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Recipe Power"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/recipeP"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Microwave Power"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/microwaveP"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Recipe Time"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <EditText
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/recipeT"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:onClick="calculate" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity

```
package com.microwave;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText microwaveP;
EditText recipeP;
EditText recipeT;
TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void calculate(View view){


        int recipePower = Integer.parseInt(recipeP.getText().toString());
        int microwavePower = Integer.parseInt(microwaveP.getText().toString());
        int recipeTime = Integer.parseInt(recipeT.getText().toString());
        int difference = recipePower - microwavePower;
        int differencePercent = recipePower / difference;
        int microwaveTime = recipeTime * differencePercent;
        result.setText(microwaveTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize your views after setContentView

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace when posting here. It will help us to help you easier. Also, after you initialize those `Views`, I would recommend doiing some error checking when parsing the text.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks have added full stacktrace

Comment: Follow the target link. That will show you the problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after setContentView to initialize your views:

```
microwaveP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.microwaveP);
recipeP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeP);
recipeT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeT);
result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
```

Comment: Just tried that, same problem